# How to solve for the coefficients of a polynomial such that the function is monotonically increasing?

Tags: functions, polynomials, regression, monotone-functions

Currently, I am solving for the coefficients of a quintic polynomial that passes through two states:

$f(x) = c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2 + c_3x^3 + c_4x^4 + c_5x^5$

The states define $f(x)$, $f'(x)$, and $f''(x)$ at $x=0$ and $x=x_f$ so the problem has an exact solution. Also, $f(x_f) > f(x_0) >= 0$.

Now, however, I want to enforce the constraint that $f(x)$ be monotonically increasing, i.e. $f'(x) >= 0$, on $[0, x_f]$

I know that I can't necessarily achieve this *and* have the function pass exactly through both states, so I'll redefine the problem to be generating a quintic polynomial that:

- passes through the first state,
- is monotonically increasing on $[0, x_f]$, and
- comes as close to passing through the second state as possible.

I have two questions:

1. What are my options for solving this problem? I suppose this is some sort of optimisation problem.
2. Is it possible to solve the problem exactly (such that the polynomial is monotonically increasing *and* passes through both states) if I increase the order of the polynomial?

Comment: Obviously it **might** not be possible, e.g. if $f(0) > f(x_f)$ and $x_f > 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good point. I should have added that that will never be the case.

Comment: @jlev "*$f(x)$ be monotonically increasing*" $\;-\;$ On $\,[0,x_f]\,$, or on $\,\mathbb R^+\,$, or ...?

Comment: I suppose it will also never be the case that $f'(0)<0$ or $f'(x_f)<0$.

Comment: If "the second state" is the specified values for the triple $(f(x_f), f'(x_f), f''(x_f))$, what is "close to" that second state?

Comment: @dxiv another good point. On $[0, x_f]$. Will add that.

Comment: @aschepler I suppose I'll have to come up with a cost function.